# google/cloud-firestore v1.19.2 requires ext-grpc * -> no matching package found

Tags: php, firebase, heroku, composer-php, grpc

I'm pushing my php application on heroku by command `git push heroku main`
But i'm getting this error

```
remote:  !     > Loading repositories with available runtimes and extensions
remote:  !     > Updating dependencies
remote:  !     > Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
remote:  !     >
remote:  !     >   Problem 1
remote:  !     >     - Installation request for google/cloud-firestore v1.19.2 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v1.19.2].
remote:  !     >     - google/cloud-firestore v1.19.2 requires ext-grpc * -> no matching package found.
```

I know this is because I've downloaded grpc.dll file and put in ext folder and wrote `extension=grpc` in php.ini file.
Hence this worked locally.
But how should I make this work on Heroku ?